# Is it possible to have a forceNetwork plot of the networkD3 package that is reactive to selectinput?

Tags: r, shiny, networkd3

I am trying plot using forceNetwork, I would like the plot to be reactive to selectinput. I am doing this in r shiny. I am  getting the error that there are undefined columns

Comment: Please add a minimal reproducible example of your app. Here's how: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example